# create-react-app command fails, how to undo a npm set registry command

Tags: reactjs, npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

I accidentally run this command on my terminal npm set registry:

- `http://localhost:4873/`
- `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli`

while exploring react-native and it has now messed up with my `create-react-app` yarn command (to create a react starter app) I know this because I get this error

> FetchError: request to http://localhost:4873/yarn failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873   ...

Any suggestions on how to fix it. My versions `npm`, `yarn`, `node`

- npm -v6.4.1
- node v10.14.2
- yarn v1.12.3
- brew v1.8.6 homebrew-core#cdd30, homebrew-cask#580d7

Here is the full error code when I try to reinstall the `create-react-app` cli

```
npm install -g create-react-app yarn
Password:
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://localhost:4873/yarn failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to http://localhost:4873/yarn failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR!   message:
npm ERR!    'request to http://localhost:4873/yarn failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'FetchError: request to http://localhost:4873/yarn failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)\n    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Do you have a `~/.npmrc` file? I don't think you can undo a change to the set registry but you could delete that file to reset it to defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue, I have register `http` (not secure). Works for me.

```
$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
$ npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `~/.npmrc`, if it exists. When you run `npm set registry` it typically saves the setting to that file.

Comment: but thank you very much that actually reminded me to uninstall and reinstall yarn. It is back to default now and working :)